# Андроид. Всплывающий снизу меню

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Очень понравилась красивая меню в приложении StacExchange которое всплывает снизу когда нажимаешь на кнопку archivements сверху. Как такое же реализовать. Ничего об этом не нашел и не знаю точного имени этой штуки. Пытался сформировать гуглу но получал лишь popup menu. Если знаете материал об этом был бы блогадарен.

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужен `BottomSheet`

Comment: Добавляйте в декор активности вашу вью и анимируйте ее...

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего они использовали *CoordinatorLayout* почитайте о нем в документации, крайне интересная штука )